# Is there a way to replace accents with Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a `varchar` column and i want to replace all [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_precomposed_Latin_characters_in_Unicode) with normal letters

For example:

- In: `São Paulo` Out: `Sao Paulo`
- In: `eéíãç` Out: `eeiac`

Comment: Updated my answer with encoding you may want to use. Please consider adding additional context/details to your question for others that may be encountering similar issues.

Comment: If it's actually *all* diacritics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_precomposed_Latin_characters_in_Unicode) it's really hard, you might create a huge list and `otranslate` to the base character. If you hide it in a SQL UDF it would be easy to use. But the best solution is probably based on a C-UDF, search for existing C-code doing this and then you just have to wrap it in a TD C-UDF

Comment: appreciate all your thoughts and so i'll keep trying it by using Translate, SQL UDF or C-UDF

Comment: What's the character type of the base column? LATIN or UNICODE?

Comment: By default teradata has been setting LATIN when i create varchar columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diacritical character is a composite character, i.e. can be a base char plus a diacritic, e.g.

```
   'a' +  '´' =  'á'
  0061 + 00B4 = 00E1
```

Both `006100B4` and `00E1` result in the same character, Unicode allows to switch back and forth using *normalization* functions, which are supported by Teradata:

```
translate(string using UNICODE_TO_UNICODE_NFD)
```

decomposes a composite character into separate characters. Those *Combining Diacritical Marks* are in a Unicode block ranging from U+0300 to U+036F.

Now decompose the input and apply a Regular Expression to remove characters from this range:

```
select
   'Ťĥïŝ ẅåš á şťŕĭńġ ŵïţĥ ḿäṇȳ ḓìāčṝĩţïĉș' as str,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(translate(str using UNICODE_TO_UNICODE_NFD) -- decomposed input
                 ,'[\x{0300}-\x{036F}]'                        -- diacritics
                 ,'')
```

returns

```
Ťĥïŝ ẅåš á şťŕĭńġ ŵïţĥ ḿäṇȳ ḓìāčṝĩţïĉș
This was a string with many diacritics
```

If there are other decomposable characters you might need to compose them again to save space using another `translate(... using UNICODE_TO_UNICODE_NFC)`

If you input string has a LATIN charset it might be easier to find the limited list of diacritical characters and apply translate:

```
oTranslate(str, 'àáâãäåÀÁÂÃÄÅÇ...', 'aaaaaaAAAAAAC...')
```

Comment: I'll check your answer because that code with regex solved my examples but when i tried with your example it returns `This ?a a string with ?a?? ?iac?itic?`, do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Does the original or the replaced string look like this? Check your session character set and your client font.

Comment: the replaced, i was using ASCII as connection session character, also i tried UTF8 but had error when insert: `The string contains an untranslatable character`. I can't use LATIN1250_1A0 because it raises: `databases does not support...`. Should i start a new question?

Comment: What's your client? Of course, ASCII doesn't support some of those characters, but UTF-16 or UTF-8 should work. The *untranslatable* error is strange, you wrote *when insert*: did you try to insert it into a LATIN column?

Comment: Caution, I had a typo (missing x) in my Unicode range, which will remove additinal characters, fixed.