# Identify records in a unicode column which satisfies a particular regex pattern - Teradata

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I am dealing with a table which has two columns, first_name and last_name which are set to be non casespecific unicode columns.

```
case when (REGEXP_SIMILAR(trim(first_name),'.*[\u0000-\u017F]+.*','i') = 1 
            or 
            REGEXP_SIMILAR(trim(first_name),'.*[\uFF00-\uFFEF]+.*','i') = 1) 
     then 'Y' else 'N' end allowed_y_n
```

With the help of the above query i am trying to identify and flag latin names with accents in those columns.

But i am facing the following error, `The pattern specified is not a valid pattern.`

Any help here is appreciated, TIA

Comment: You can [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64281053/2527905) to decompose accented characters and then search for accents using `'[\x{0300}-\x{036F}]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata uses [Perl 5 syntax and semantics](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2019/Regular-Expression-Functions/Overview).

For Perl use `\x{....}` instead of `\u`.

So your regex should look like this:

```
.*[\x{0000}-\x{017F}]+.*
```